# Access Query Running Master Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table in access that hold part number, part name, and total $ owed. I want to make a query takes the Total $ owed and have it put into another table that names that column as the date the query is run. Every time the query is run then it will insert a new column into the table with that days Total $ owed. Below are visual examples that I mocked up in excel.

Data Source:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

I've tried some make querys and append querys but almost broke my database.

Comment: Implementing process that routinely modifies table structure is poor design. Limit of 255 fields in table - would you expect to exceed that? Saving calculated data is usually unnecessary and bad design.

Comment: It would never exceed the 255 limit, it would only be ran once a month and if the data would be archived after 4-5 years. I would rather with be moved to excel but the boss want this format in access table.

Comment: If it's only once a month, then are those dates in dd/mm/yyyy structure? If you want to add a field to table, that would be an ALTER TABLE action. Then run an UPDATE action to populate field.

Comment: The date would have to be in mm/dd/yyyy because the query could be ran more than once during a month if it we want a quicker update. How would I add a blank column to a table?

Comment: Suggest you research ALTER TABLE action SQL https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_alter.asp

Comment: I figured out the ALTER TABLE part but that requires a static name to be entered. the Update query then refers to that name but if I change the name to the current date then the reference changes also.

Comment: Yes, if you use query objects, will have to modify each time. Alternatively, use VBA to construct and execute action SQL statements.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was able to make the code that does what I want.